# Cakephp Models not associating..Containable not working in live server

Tags: cakephp, associations, containable

The project works fine with my local and dev server. But when uploading to live server, it seems to throw Model xxx is not associated with model ccc. The associations are working fine in both local and live servers. Even we uploaded the files twice to live server and checked the naming conventions. We are unable to trace the issue. Can anyone help on this? Please let me know

Comment: Can you add more details? Like what exact line is giving you trouble (I realize it may be a lot of lines, but just give and example). And also details about your live and dev server (php version, etc etc)

Comment: Yes this is the error Iam getting in live server.

Warning (512): Model "Translation" is not associated with model "Language" [CORE/cake/libs/model/behaviors/containable.php, line 0]
Notice (8): Undefined index:  Language [CORE/cake/libs/model/behaviors/containable.php, line 0]

Comment: Notice (8): Trying to get property of non-object [CORE/cake/libs/model/behaviors/containable.php, line 0]
Both the live and dev servers are PHP Version 5.2.17
MySql - dev 5.1.68
Mysql - live  5.0.51a 
cakephp version 2.0

Comment: Also I am getting 
Notice (8): Trying to get property of non-object [CORE/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 0]
Warning (512): SQL Error: 1054: Unknown column 'Language.iso2' in 'where clause' [CORE/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 0]
Query: SELECT `Translation`.`key`, `Translation`.`lang_text` FROM `translations` AS `Translation` WHERE `Language`.`iso2` = 'en'

Comment: what DBMS are you using? The DBMS settings are the same in the two servers.

Comment: Finally the issue seems to be with hosting server, as it does not support PHP cake. Thanks for all your support

Comment: I have the same Issue... Works fine on dev linux server or on local windows xampp but not working on other machine. I mea everything works but I get the error with the containable models not being associated